# Is it possible to add elements to a list, and have the list save these values even after closing an Emacs session?

Tags: session, emacs

I have a variable called `my-projects` that points to a list of strings of my current projects (e.g., `"chores"`, `"lectures"`, etc.). Whenever I call a function, say `(completing-read ...)`, and I happen to create a new project on the fly, I would like to have a function that adds this new project to the list of projects forever. What I can't figure out is how to "save" the updated list `my-projects` so that it keeps the newly added values even after the end of the current Emacs session. I can only come up with convoluted solutions involving replacing strings in the file where the variable `my-projects` is defined, but I surmise that there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can use library `savehist.el` to save minibuffer inputs, so you can access them when reading minibuffer input in future sessions. E.g. a similar `completing-read` in a future session will let you use `M-p` or `M-r` to access those previous inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by developing a function that saves your data structure to a file.

```
(defvar my-projects
  '("chores"
    "lectures"))

(defun my-save-my-projects ()
  "Saves my projects in my home folder."
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (prin1-to-string my-projects))
    (write-region (point-min)
                  (point-max)
                  "~/.my-projects.eld")))
```

Next you may want to find a suitable event that you can hook your saving function onto. For example, you could save your project list whenever Emacs closes down:

```
(when (not (memq 'my-save-my-projects kill-emacs-hook))
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            'my-save-my-projects)))
```

There may be better hooks for your use-case.

Ultimately, you will want to repopulate your variable by reading in that file when Emacs starts. I'll leave that out here (or as an "exercise to the reader" ;-). There's plenty of examples out there.

Comment: I consider the above code trivial and don't claim any copyright on it. You're free to use it in any way in addition to the StackOverflow default of CC-BY-SA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `defcustom` to create a user-customizable variable. Emacs already has built-in ways to persist the value of customized variables. Use `customize-var` to interactively update its value when you start a new project.